# Function whose $n^{th}$ derivative at $x=0$ is $(n!)^2$

Tags: calculus, functions, taylor-expansion

There exists a function in math where $$f^{(n)}(0)=(n!)^2$$
They say there's an analytical formula for this function but I do not know how to find it. I am investigating functions who cannot be represented with Taylor Polynomials and this is one of the examples I came about. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try $f(x)=n!x^n \hspace{1cm}$

Comment: Integration is (to an extent) the reverse operation to differentiation. If $f$ becomes $g$ after $n$ differentiations, we should plausibly be able to generate an $f$ from $n$ integrations of $g$, i.e., Elliot's answer.

Comment: One $f$ for all $n$? In other words, the Taylor series "should" be $\sum n!x^n$?

Comment: Yes that is Correct. The Taylor Series for this supposed function should be $\sum n!x^n$. Applying the Ratio Test will result in a radius of convergence of zero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the function via Borel summation:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {n!z^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - t} t^n dt} z^n }  = \int_0^\infty  {e^{ - t} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(zt)^n } dt}  = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{1 - zt}}dt} .
$$
Along the path of integration, $\Re t$ must tend to $+\infty$ and it must omit the singularity at $t=1/z$. Note that
$$
\left[ {\frac{{d^n }}{{dz^n }}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{1 - zt}}dt} } \right]_{z = 0}  = \left[ {n!\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - t} t^n }}{{(1 - zt)^{n + 1} }}dt} } \right]_{z = 0}  = n!\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - t} t^n dt}  = (n!)^2 .
$$